# Pass dynamic data type to function

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, dynamic

I have the following function:

```
private string ParseJson(dynamic q)
    {
        string returnJSON = "[{ \"type\" : \"pie\", \"name\" : \"Campaigns\", \"data\" : [ ";
        foreach (var grp in q)
        {
            double currCount = grp.Count();
            if (grp.Key != null)
                returnJSON += "['" + grp.Key + "', " + currCount + "],";
            else
                returnJSON += "['none', " + currCount + "],";
        }
        returnJSON = returnJSON.Substring(0, returnJSON.Length - 1);
        returnJSON += "]}]";

        return returnJSON;
    }
```

I call it from methods like this one:

```
public string GetCampaignData()
    {
        PaymentModelDataContext db = new PaymentModelDataContext();
        var q = from Event in db.TrackingEvents
                group Event by Event.campaignID;


        return ParseJson(q);

    }
```

I use q for several different queries, all grouping data.

The problem is that the runtime can't bind a type to q for some reason. Is this a proper use of dynamic? Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: I get an error, because the object type (and thus structure) is unknown, there is no Count property.

Comment: .Count() is an extension method and doesn't exists on the Grouping IIRC. This probably gives the error that .Count is missing. Is it possible to refactor the code to not use dynamic as I personally don't see a good reason to use it? Also you don't parse JSON you write JSON.

Comment: Instead of accepting a `dynamic`, your method should accept an [`IGrouping<TKey, TElement>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx)

Comment: I know this is not your original question but have you concidered using the `JavaScriptSerializer`? This might be better than creating your own JSON

Comment: @John: I agree dynamic isn't probably best use, since it's a collection of them, he should use `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey,TValue>>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `Count()` is an extension method off of `IEnumerable<T>`, as such it can't be called from dynamic (because it's not a true method of the class).

Your variable grp is also dynamic because it results from an expression on dynamic variable q:

```
foreach (var grp in q)
```

Since we can't call extension methods off of dynamic (again, they aren't true members of the class), we need to explicitly call the extension method instead off the `Enumerable` static class.  So change your code to:

```
double currCount = Enumerable.Count(grp);
```

And you'll see it work properly for the `Count()`, *if* you want to really use `dynamic`.

That said, I do agree with @John's comment that you should consider changing this to a non-dynamic.  Actually, what your method would accept would be an IEnumerable> like so:

```
private string ParseJson<TKey,TValue>(IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey,TValue>> q)
    {
        string returnJSON = "[{ \"type\" : \"pie\", \"name\" : \"Campaigns\", \"data\" : [ ";
        foreach (var grp in q)
        {
            double currCount = grp.Count();
            if (grp.Key != null)
                returnJSON += "['" + grp.Key + "', " + currCount + "],";
            else
                returnJSON += "['none', " + currCount + "],";
        }
        returnJSON = returnJSON.Substring(0, returnJSON.Length - 1);
        returnJSON += "]}]";

        return returnJSON;
    }
```

You can also make the parameter type non-generic specific to your usage if you like.  But this would work with all groupings...

Comment: Yeah, interesting, i was more answering his question on the error on Count...  Let me dig more.

Comment: Thank you! I always assumed a dynamic type just gets its type bound @ runtime, which would imply you can do ANYTHING with it during compilation, and any errors would occur @ runtime. It should be used with caution anyway, so if I'm using it, let me do whatever I want. That's my take, anyway :)